# Unable to call a PIG macro inside a FOREACH block

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I am unable to call a macro from within a foreach, example

```
 DEFINE valid_attribute(id,attribute)
    RETURNS result {
            data       =       LOAD '/user/sathish/sessAttr' AS (id:chararray,browser_version:chararray);
         filtered_data      = FILTER data BY id == '$id' AND $attribute is NOT null;
         $result            = foreach filtered_data generate $attribute;
    };

    ip = load '/user/sathish/macros/inputParams' AS (id:chararray,attribute:chararray);
    op = foreach ip {generate valid_attribute('ip::id','ip:attribute');};
    dump op;
```

I am getting the below exception when calling the same :

```
2013-06-25 04:47:42,239 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve valid_attribute using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a macro in this manner.  A macro returns a relation (table), not an individual value.  `GENERATE` is for producing individual values in your relation.  The way you have used your macro looks like you are trying to use a UDF, which is why Pig looks in its default classpath to find the function, as it would for any UDF.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, If I am goin to write an UDF, how would I compare my input arguments to the UDF with entire dataset which I am trying to load here ?

Comment: I don't follow your question, but looking at your script I think you may be trying to do something similar to a `JOIN`?  See if you can accomplish what you want to do in Pig Latin before resorting to a UDF.

Comment: ya we can do the same in Pig Latin, here the attribute is a column name and the scenario is we have to do the same process for multiple columns which will result in writing multiple join statements. Hence trying to modularize the code as a function which can be used for n number of columns.

Comment: Then you need to write a macro that performs the join.  A macro is not a function.  It's basically automated search-and-replace.  You cannot use it inside a Pig Latin statement, it is its own statement.